# May I use "naive" to mean "inexperienced"?

Tags: word-meaning, connotations

Sometimes I may use "naive" in sentences like

> I am naive in writing this type of articles

To say "inexperienced"

I would like to know how common this word is among native speakers of English, or in which situations they use it (through some examples please).

Comment: I'm downvoting, Ahmad, because you have been shown the fishing rod and the tackle box. *Where they most use it* is a very broad question, and it is one you could answer for yourself. You can consult the texts returned by clicking on the hyperlinks at the bottom of the page here. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=naive&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnaive%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano maybe I should correct it, by *where they most use it*, simply I mean its basic or common usage (by an example maybe), for example one can answer *it is most used to describe a child or a gullible person...* (as it is in the answer), then what should I have said to mean that?

Comment: An even better question: "Is my use of *naive* correct? If not, an example would help."

Comment: @TRomano I edited the question.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but "in writing this type of articles" should probably be written as either "in writing **these types** of articles" or "in writing this type of **article**".

Comment: "Natives" is absolutely, absolutely not the same as "native English speakers". What my dictionary says (among others): "Native, noun, dated or offensive: A non-white original inhabitant of a country, as regarded by European colonists or travellers."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Be careful. *[Naive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive) (adjective) or naivety (noun)* carry more a sense of attitude than of experience.

If you are *naive*, you tend to:

- believe everything you are told
- believe that people are  good
- be easily tricked.
  Even if you were tricked many times and hence in theory are experienced

Children are the standard example of naive.

If you want to say inexperienced, write *inexperienced*. You could also describe yourself as a *[novice](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/novice)* or *[beginner](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beginner)*.

Comment: Good answer.  As a native speaker, I would add that I've never seen "naive in [something]"; it looks wrong to me.  Naivete is a general condition.  I don't think you can narrow it by field.

Comment: Though you can be e.g. naive in business, so perhaps you can apply naivete to general areas of interest or endeavour.

Comment: I disagree that believing people are good is a valid use of naive.

Answer (score 9):

Naiveté is a result of inexperience; it is not inexperience *per se*.  To be *naive* is to not know that one's knowledge and experience are insufficient in a given context. Therefore, it is impossible to say "I am naive". One can only say "I *was* naive." But one *can* say "I am inexperienced".

Comment: Well, but if I can say "I was naive" and suspect that I may still is, can't I say "I feel I am still naive". And I think you mean it is most used by others to describe someone not the person himself.

Comment: In Persian, I think of two equivalent for this phrase *Saade Loh* means gullible and easy believe... and maybe *Khaam* (like raw fruits), one who is very inexperienced and lack the knowledge of his situation...

Comment: To render the judgment "he is naive" one must have the knowledge and experience to see that his are insufficient. He may be naive to think that taking vitamins will cure his disease. He may be naive to think that his children are not using recreational drugs.  He may be naive to think that a neighborhood is safe to walk in at night.  Once one has seen that one has been naive, one may doubt thenceforward whether one is seeing all that needs to be seen. In that case, one might possibly say *I still feel naive* when *remembering* the feeling  one had when one realized one's (now former) naiveté.

Comment: But if you mean to say that you still do not possess the requisite experience for a given context, you would not use the word "naive". Rather you would say "I still lack sufficient experience in such matters" or "I don't know enough about this topic yet".  As I said, to be naive is to *not know* that one's knowledge and experience are insufficient.

Comment: If you wanted to get fancy-schmancy, you could say "I am *a naif* in such matters." But that is a quasi-literary expression. It is a *sophisticate's* way of saying "this 'terrain' is unknown to me".

Comment: Maybe we can't say "I am naive," but I've often heard "Maybe I'm just being naive, but..."

Comment: @Dan Henderson: True.  By "we can't *say* that we are naive" I mean "we can't *assert* that we are naive". If we know that we do not know, we are not "naive" but something else. Socratically wise, perhaps. We can certainly *wonder* or *question* or *express doubt* about whether we're not seeing something that  greater knowledge and experience would allow us to see for what it is. "Maybe I'm just being naive..." is an expression of such doubt.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, we use this word when talking about people  when we feel they believe everything they hear, or take things at face value, or can easily be convinced to do anything:

> A: He said he was going to leave his wife and marry me!
>
> B: That was five years ago and they're *still* together. Don't be so
>   naive!

It's not always a reproach - sometimes it just means *innocent* and *unsuspecting*:

> She entered college a mousy, **naive** girl, and came out a confident,
>   savvy businesswoman.

It is also sometimes used to describe someone's actions, who doesn't suspect anything is amiss in a given situation:

> "They made up a profile for a girl named Debbie on a dating site.
>   "Debbie" sent me her email address and I wrote her several times to
>   ask her out. They must have gotten a lot of laughs from my **naive**
>   attempts to meet her."

Comment: Thank you, by your answer you added to new words to my .....?!

Comment: ...vocabulary! :) Which words?

Comment: Yes you added *savvy*, *mousy* and *vocabulary* to my vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

You've got excellent answers regarding the meaning and the use of the word **naive**, but I would try to explain the meaning of your phrasing instead:

> I am naive in writing this type of article.

This would mean that you came to the conclusion that someone too easily persuaded/convinced you to write this type of article regardless the consequences, in other words, that's not the lack of experience in writing this type of article but the lack of assessment/judgement/discernment of the article's subject.

Comment: Thank you, then I think it is *I **was** naive in writing this type of articles*?

Comment: Yes, past would fit better

Comment: Lucian, @Ahmad, I would say "this type of article" (no 's' on the end).

Comment: @snailboat, yes that's very correct. I don't know how I missed it, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Naive also means being simple and unaffected. It can refer to a lack of sophistication as well. So a naive young man or a naive villager, could also refer to, depending on the context, somebody who is simple and artless. You can say the village girl exuded a naive charm - in which case the word is used in a positive complimentary sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have also heard it used in the context of art, Naive Art, meaning childlike / simple in the artistic technique.

I have heard the art of LS Lowry described this way for example.

As others have said, naive tends to be something you say of others "he was naive to believe her" whereas in your sentence I would use inexperience.